# JsonSchema: How make sure that an object requires one/specific properties?

Tags: jsonschema

I have an object to define, that needs needs one key or another specific key. 
Basically a simple or: if(key1 || key2){ -> valid} else {-> invalid}

Now I know of the "require" keyword, but that it isn't able to require keys conditionally as far as I know. 
In my case I want to exactly key1 or key2 to exists.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "/my_schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "key1": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "key2": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    "key3": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "string",
        "minItems": 1
      }
    },
    "key4": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "begin": {
          "type": "number"
        },
        "end": {
          "type": "number"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "key3", "key4"
  ]
}
```

If possible, I look for something where I could define an object conditionally like this e.g.:

```
"required": {
    "key1": if(someConditions), 
    "key2": if(someOtherConditions)
}
```

or even this:

```
"porperties":{
     "key1":{
         "type": someType,
         "required": if(someCondition)
     }
}
```

But right now I simply want to make sure that key1 or key2 are required and that the schema is invalid if both are missing.

Answer (score 1):

To validate at least one of two attributes must be required, you could use `anyOf` blocks like this.

```
"properties": {...},
"required":[
   "key3", 
   "key4"
],
"anyOf": [
  {
    "required": [
      "key1"
    ]
  },
  {
    "required": [
      "key2"
    ]
  }
]
```

To validate availability based on some condition you could use `if` `then` `else` keywords. For example,

If key1 = "1", then key2 is required. Otherwise, key3 is required

```
"if": {
  "key1": {
    "const": "1" // some simple condition 
  }
},
"then": {
  "required": [
    "key2"
  ]
},
"else": {
  "required": [
    "key3"
  ]
}
```

Comment: The proposed first solution sounds like what the OP is asking, and would be preferable in this case.